# ios-webkit-debug-proxy gets disconnected from ipad while running tests

Tags: ios, ipad, testing, proxy, appium

I am trying to run test on physical iPad. I am using appium and webkit-ios-debug-proxy. But ios-webkit-debug-proxy gets disconnected when i try to run tests. It gives an error -

```
Invalid message _rpc_applicationUpdated: <dict>
<key>WIRApplicationIdentifierKey</key>
<string>PID...</string>
<key>WIRIsApplicationProxyKey</key>
<false/>
<key>WIRApplicationNameKey</key>
...
</dict>
Disconnected
```

I found some forums, where it was mentioned to run command -

```
.bin/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js -c UDID -d
```

from the appium folder, but when I run the command, I get an error -

```
"module.js: ..throw err Error: Cannot find module 
'underscore' at Function.Module_resolveFuleName (module.js:336:15) ....
```

So that solution does not work for me either.

Comment: can you give the exact command you ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command above in the question [.bin/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js -c UDID -d ], worked for me eventually.

It wasn't initially working as I was downloading ios-webkit-debug-proxy-launcher.js again from github instead of looking for the .js file in current installation, and also, I guess some ports where not freed from the previous ios_webkit_debug_proxy run. Hence it was throwing an error. In most cases the installation on mac, it should be on /use/local/lib/..

Also, to find and kill existing instances, this worked for me -

```
ps aux | grep portNumber
```

OR

```
ps -efl | grep ios_webkit_debug_proxy
```

and then

```
kill -9 PID
```